# How to add a padding to a KeyboardView in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a row of keys. Each key is 18.5% width with 2% gap. I however want the gap on the first key to be 10% and the gap on the last key to be **10% on the right side**. It's simple to set the horizontalGap on each key to achieve this effect, except I see no way to set the right side gap.

The spacing I want is as follows (bracketed items are keys, else it's a gap):

```
10% [18.5%] 2% [18.5%] 2% [18.5%] 2% [18.5%] 10%
```

I have tried:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="18.5%p"
    android:horizontalGap="2%"
    android:keyHeight="7%p">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1" android:keyLabel="1" android:horizontalGap="10%p" />
        <Key android:codes="2" android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key android:codes="3" android:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key android:codes="4" android:keyLabel="4"  />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

This does not give me a 10% gap despite by KeyboardView width set to fill_parent. How can my keyboard have a 10% gap after the keys in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width to wrap_content and center it horizontally within its parent.

Comment: That does not work. My keyboard is 90% of the screen width and centered using that technique, leaving blank space on either side. It needs to fill the screen width with the dimensions given in the original question.

Comment: There is no way to do percentage padding in android, without being EXTREMELY wasteful.  The correct answer here is to make the keyboard the size you want and center it.  If this causes the background to not stretch, apply the background to the parent view instead.

Comment: As you suggested, I ended up wrapping it with a LinearLayout and setting its padding. The KeyboardView then stretches within that. The KeyboardView is given a transparent background and the LinearLayout is given the background.